# Converting tensor product from one coordinate to another

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, matrix-calculus, multilinear-algebra

This is a long multi-steps question and I'm stuck at the last leg. I believe my question to be trivial but after 3 hrs of staring and trying all sort of methods (ridiculous ones even) I'm not getting anywhere.
Frustrating!

I shall jump straight to the problem I am facing and provide prior information leading to this.

[image]

I do not understand how I can arrive at the corresponding matrix field in the last line.

The prior worked out basis products are:

[image]

The given polar coordinates are 
[image]

In Euclidean coordinate, Q and R

[image]
I really need help and appreciate any.
Thanks in advance

Comment: No help guys? Either my question is unclear or I'm learning stuffs which no one knows about?

Comment: it seems that the symbolic conventions you are using aren't standard, which are the references?

Answer (score 1):

You already have the basis for the matrices; it is $\{\boldsymbol{e_{1}}\otimes\boldsymbol{e^{1}}, \boldsymbol{e_{1}}\otimes\boldsymbol{e^{2}},\boldsymbol{e_{2}}\otimes\boldsymbol{e^{1}}, \boldsymbol{e_{2}}\otimes\boldsymbol{e^{2}}\}$. This means that a matrix $\boldsymbol{M}$, under this basis, given by
$$\boldsymbol{M}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d \end{array}\right),$$
is $$\boldsymbol{M}= a\,(\boldsymbol{e_{1}}\otimes\boldsymbol{e^{1}}) + b\,(\boldsymbol{e_{1}}\otimes\boldsymbol{e^{2}}) + c\,(\boldsymbol{e_{2}}\otimes\boldsymbol{e^{1}})+d\,(\boldsymbol{e_{2}}\otimes\boldsymbol{e^{2}}).$$